# Chosen and Selectize both conflicting with other jQuery code in MVC5 form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-chosen, selectize.js

I have several multiple select elements on a page and I've tried to use both the Chosen and the Selectize plugins with them. Other jQuery code, for example to show or hide elements, works until I add the initialisation code for Chosen or Selectize to the page and then it stops working altogether.

Is there any reason for this? Example of code:

```
if ($('input#R_COL_Quality:checked').val() == 'Poor') {
    $("#R_COL_IfQualityPoor").show();
} else {
    $("#R_COL_IfQualityPoor").hide();
}

$('#L_COL_GridRegions').selectize({ create: true, maxItems: 2 });
$('#L_COL_IfAMD').selectize({ create: true });
```

jQuery loads before Selectize, I've got the right CSS loading before the scripts, and I've tried wrapping it in document ready, in function() and on its own, as well as changing the code order. Any insights?

Comment: Does the selectize code work? Do you end up with selectized boxes at least?

Comment: Yes, if I don't put any other code in at all the selectize elements are grand. There's a requirement though not to show any questions that aren't necessary so there are lots of fields hidden and only shown based on the value of another field so getting the other code to work alongside selectize is vital

Comment: "if I don't put any other code in at all".. to clarify, I meant do they work WITH your `.show()`/`.hide()` code. Does selectize work but the show/hide code doesn't? Or do they both end up breaking?

Comment: If I start off with only the selectize code it works. If I add other code then selectize still works but the other code doesn't. On a page where I have other code and I add selectize in later, then selectize doesn't work as expected. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I read another post regarding plugins where the user could only get all their plugins working without conflict by updating jQuery. Just updated from 1.10.2 to 2.1.3 and I'm not clear on why this would have worked, but all the code is functioning as expected now. Hopefully this might help someone else too, wasted way too much time on this one!